# VS code - Context Actions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I am using python and came from Pycharm to vs code. In Pycharm, while writing a constructor of a class I have an option to put the mouse on a method argument (for example the argument `a` in the code below), press Alt+Enter and Pycharm would suggest to automatticly add the argument to the method (i.e adding the line `self.a=a` to the method)

```
class Temp:
  def __init__ (self, a):
    self.a = a
```

In addition, when I use an unimported package in the code, pressing Alt+Enter would suggest adding the import automatically.

Can I do something similar in VS code?

Comment: With the extension [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) you can define these types of actions yourself

Comment: @s.b -For automatically importing unimported packages, the "Python" extension in VS Code provides this function, you could refer to this document: [Quick Fixes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_quick-fixes)